# Saving Excel files in Python to a OneDrive Directory and then error opening the file do it being used by Python

Tags: python, excel, onedrive

My Python code properly writes to Excel using the pandas `pd.ExcelWriter` function.  The challenge I am having is that I am saving the file to a OneDrive directory and it won't let me open the file in Excel once the code is executed unless I close Python. Effectively, the Excel file is considered still be used by Python and therefore cannot get synced in OneDrive.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: Are you closing the file by calling file.close()? Make sure that after writing to the file you are calling flush and close on that file. Also, share some code snippets so we can help you better

Comment: Ok added the writer.close() at the end - it did give me an warning that I was closing a closed file but it did stop the OneDrive issue
Thx for the suggestion @AbdulelahAGR